# How to map values in a column to two other column of another dataframe and extract matching values on both columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

df1

```
NAME
AB2
AB3
AB45
AB5
AB6
AB776
AB845
AB9
AB10
```

df2

```
G1  G2  Value
AB2 AB3   5
AB3 AB2   5
AB2 AB2   4
CXY AB3   0
AB3 GTZ   8
AB5 AB6   4
AB9 NUT3    6
CVC FGT   5
MKH CTY   8
LMN VUT   9
AB776   AB776   1
AB845   AB776   8
```

I want to map values of `df1['NAME']` to `df2['G1']` and `df2['G2']` and extract columns matching the values.

I tried as follows:

```
df = df2[df2['G1'].isin(df1['NAME']) | df2['G2'].isin(df1['NAME'])]
```

But it extracts all values matching single column also. I want to return if it maps to both the columns

Expected output is:

```
G1    G2    Value
AB2   AB3   5
AB3   AB2   5
AB2   AB2   4
AB5   AB6   4
AB776   AB776   1
AB845   AB776   8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `&` condition instead of `|`:

```
df2[df2['G1'].isin(df1['NAME']) & df2['G2'].isin(df1['NAME'])]
```

Output:

```
       G1     G2  Value
0     AB2    AB3      5
1     AB3    AB2      5
2     AB2    AB2      4
5     AB5    AB6      4
10  AB776  AB776      1
11  AB845  AB776      8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `&`:

```
In [1242]: df2[df2['G1'].isin(df1['NAME']) & df2['G2'].isin(df1['NAME'])]
Out[1242]: 
       G1     G2  Value
0     AB2    AB3      5
1     AB3    AB2      5
2     AB2    AB2      4
5     AB5    AB6      4
10  AB776  AB776      1
11  AB845  AB776      8
```